# Product scoring in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, product, segment

I do have product id dataframe. I would like to find the best product by scoring each product. For each variable the more the value the better the product score except returns which means more returns less score.Also I need to assign different weight to score for the variables Shipped revenue and returns that maybe increased by 20 percent of their importance.

A scoring function can look like this
Score=ShippedUnits+1.2*ShippedRevenue+OrderedUnits-1.2Returns+View+Stock
where 0<=Score<=100

Please help. Thank you.

```
 df_product=pd.DataFrame({'ProductId':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],'ShippedUnits': 
 [6,8,0,4,27,3,4,14,158,96],'ShippedRevenue':[268,1705,1300,950,1700,33380,500,2200,21000,24565]
 ,'OrderedUnits':[23,78,95,52,60,76,68,92,34,76],'Returns':[0,0,6,0,2,5,6,5,2,13],'View': 
 [0,655,11,378,920,12100,75,1394,12368,14356],'Stock':[24,43,65,27,87,98,798,78,99,231]
             })
```

Comment: given your ```dataframe``` what you expect to get?

Comment: Actually I added the question a score for each product btw 0 and 100 thanks

Comment: Your weights do not ensure the score to fall in range [0, 100].

Comment: that's fine it can be more than 100 but can we than squeeze all score to 100 Thanks

Comment: This is one way to achieve it,
`w = np.array([1,1.2,1,-1.2,1, 1])`

`score = df_product.drop('ProductId', axis=1).apply(lambda x: sum(w*x), axis=1)`


`normalizedScore = 100*(score - score.min())/(score.max() - score.min())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 df_product=pd.DataFrame({'ProductId':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','10'],'ShippedUnits': 
 [6,8,0,4,27,3,4,14,158,96],'ShippedRevenue':[268,1705,1300,950,1700,33380,500,2200,21000,24565]
 ,'OrderedUnits':[23,78,95,52,60,76,68,92,34,76],'Returns':[0,0,6,0,2,5,6,5,2,13],'View': 
 [0,655,11,378,920,12100,75,1394,12368,14356],'Stock':[24,43,65,27,87,98,798,78,99,231]
             })
df_product['score'] = df_product['ShippedUnits'] +1.2*df_product['ShippedRevenue']+df_product['OrderedUnits']-1.2*df_product['Returns']+df_product['View']+df_product['Stock']

df_product['score']=(df_product['score']-df_product['score'].min())/(df_product['score'].max()-df_product['score'].min())*100

df_product
```

Comment: can we squeeze the score btw 0 and 100. Thanks

Comment: maybe scale each variable btw 0 and 100 then sum ?

Comment: I normalized the column between 0-1 and multiplied by 100

Answer (score 0):

```
df["Score"] = df["ShippedUnits"] + df["OrderedUnits"] \
              + df["View"] + df["Stock"] \
              + 1.2 * df["ShippedRevenue"] \
              - 1.2 * df["Returns"]


df["Norm1"] = df["Score"] / df["Score"].max() * 100
df["Norm2"] = df["Score"] / df["Score"].sum() * 100
df["Norm3"] = (df["Score"] - df["Score"].min()) / (df["Score"].max() - df["Score"].min()) * 100
```

```
>>> df[["ProductId", "Score", "Norm1", "Norm2", "Norm3"]]
  ProductId    Score       Norm1      Norm2       Norm3
0         1    374.6    0.715883   0.250040    0.000000
1         2   2830.0    5.408298   1.888986    4.726249
2         3   1723.8    3.294284   1.150613    2.596993
3         4   1601.0    3.059606   1.068646    2.360622
4         5   3131.6    5.984673   2.090300    5.306781
5         6  52327.0  100.000000  34.927558  100.000000
6         7   1537.8    2.938827   1.026460    2.238973
7         8   4212.0    8.049382   2.811452    7.386377
8         9  37856.6   72.346208  25.268763   72.146811
9        10  44221.4   84.509718  29.517180   84.398026
```